# How to remove Google Translation Plugin when navigating to a different Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, google-translate

I have a small issue. Basically, I am building a website builder.

I have two major parts, the builder and the preview.

In the preview, I import the Google Translation plugin:

```
onMounted(() => {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({}, 'google_translate_element');
})
```

And I put the script in `index.html`, before closing `<head>`:

```
        <script
                type="text/javascript"
                src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"
        ></script>
```

However, when I navigate back to the builder and then back to the preview, my Google Translate plugin doesn't load (but onMounted is fired). I get no error in the console.

First load:
[image: first load, field is here]

Second load:
[image: second load, field isn't loaded]

I tried to remove the TranslateElement when it unmounted, but it didn't work.

Is there something else I could try?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your code in beforeUnmount hook?

Comment: @mare96 I removed the code, but it was basically putting the TranslateElement on a ref and then setting the ref to null when unmounting.

Answer (score 0):

I did it the following way here and it worked.

First, you need to place the google translator script before closing the `</body>`, this because if this script for some reason that is not in your control takes a while to load, because it is in the `</head>`, it will stop loading the page until it completes the loading of this script.

Your html will look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div>

    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>

    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now your `main.js` or `App.vue` file should contain this **function** and then its **invocation**. I used `mounted` inside `App.vue` and it worked:

```
{
mounted () {
  this.googleTranslateElementInit()
},
methods: {
  googleTranslateElementInit () {
    window.google.translate.TranslateElement(
      { pageLanguage: "en" },
      "google_translate_element"
    );
  }
}
```

Tested on vue2 and vue3.